# Why is wp_enqueue_script not loading included jquery ui scripts?

Tags: jquery-ui

Using Wordpress 3.4.2, the wp_enqueue_script documentation seems to indicate that jQuery UI libraries can be loaded simply by referencing their handles.  I have the following code with no prior wp_register_script():

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

The enqueue for 'jquery' works fine, but the enqueue for 'jquery-ui-core' isn't working.

I realize that I can register and load script explicitly using Google CDN (or make explicit references to library elements in Wordpress install) ... but again documentation makes me think I shouldn't have to do this w/ Wordpress current version.

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: The handle `jquery-ui-core` does not reference the whole core incl. all core plugins, but just the base. Other than that, the above should work and the syntax is correct.

Comment: What *isn't working*? Does `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' )` not cause *any* scripts to be enqueued? Or are you missing certain UI *libraries*? Or something else? What do you **expect** to happen, but **isn't** happening? Or what is happening **unexpectedly** or **differently** from what you expected to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting to get jquery-ui-core loaded via a <script src= ...> reference to the .js that Wordpress would add in page as a result of the wp_enqueue_script() call.  This is happening for jquery (which I'm including first) and it's happening for other libraries, just not the jquery ui libraries when I call w/ the handle (btw if I make explicit reference to Google CDN then everything works fine).

Comment: What all scripts actually load? Can we see a live link to the rendered output?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have to  [really read the Codex about `wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) again and then dig into jQuery a little bit more. jQuery UI is a *dependency* of jQuery (which means it *depends* on having jQuery loaded). So you need to load jQuery first, before loading jQuery UI (or jQuery UI Mobile).

**Edit** as per @ChipBennet and @MannyFleurmond comments below:

1. There's *no* need to add `array( 'jquery' )` as `$dependency` argument for `jquery-ui-core`, as Chip shows us in [this core reference](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L125)
2. As Manny stated, you need to add every effect/plugin by itself, like for e.g. `'jquery-effects-fold'`, `'jquery-ui-resizable'` or `'jquery-effects-explode'`.
3. The example is right, but missing the (possibly) needed plugins

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
   ```

Comment: Actually, doesn't core *register* `jquery` as a *dependency* of `jquery-ui-core`? So, calling `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' )` will *automatically* enqueue `jquery`?

Comment: @ChipBennett As it's _your_ idea, you now have to prove that fact :D

Comment: Refer to [`\wp-includes\script-loader.php`, line 125](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L125).

Comment: Don't forget that you'll also need to load any individual jQuery UI plugins that you need, as shown here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress

Comment: Ok. Edited the answer to reflect both of your comments. @Chip owe you a beer I guess ;)

Answer (score 4):

Loading jquery-ui just loads the core of the UI plugins.  If you want to load individual plugins, you'll have to load the separately:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable'); //load sortable
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs'); //load tabs
```

A complete list of what you can load is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress)

Comment: Indeed as documentation states: _jquery-ui-core (Att.: This is not the whole core incl. all core plugins. Just the base core.)_.